# Infinite quotient of Hurwitz Group

Tags: gr.group-theory

I am currently working through all the groups with two generators, and I am up to the group with presentation $G := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^9 \rangle$. I have found all the finite quotients of this group, but there are also the infinite quotients of the group that I need to check. Are there any infinite quotients of this group other than the whole group? I know that there is a central element of order 2, but what I need to know is, what is this element?

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: This was answered in your earlier question. $G$ has a central element of order 2.

Comment: Ok then, what I need to know is: What is the central element in terms of a and b? Also, is there a way to prove that there aren't any more quotients?

Comment: Sorry I'm in a hurry! It's the commutator $[x,y]$, where (for example) $x=b * a * b * a * b^-1 * a * b * a * b * a * b^-1 * a * b * a * b^-1 * a * b^-1 * 
a * b * a * b^-1 * a * b^-1 * a * b * a * b^-1 * a$, $y=b * a * b^-1 * a * b * a * b^-1 * a * b^-1 * a * b * a * b^-1 * a * b^-1 * a * b
* a * b^-1 * a * b * a * b * a * b^-1 * a * b * a$.

Comment: if you know that there is a central element of order 2 then you know that there is a proper infinite quotient group...

Comment: Wow, is there a shorter representation of it, or is that the shortest? Also, you said something about computers last time, do you have some group theory program that you are using?

Comment: "I am currently working through all the groups with two generators".  Higman, Neumann and Neumann proved that every countable group embeds in a 2-generator group. So your project may take you a while...

Comment: Yes, I'm just working on the simple (ish) cases. I'll stop when it gets too difficult.