# Simplicity of infinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Sorry about asking so many questions, but I am a bit further on in my classification, and I am up to the group $G := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{10}, ([a,b]^4b)^7 \rangle$. It has no small quotients (up to 500000), and I suspect that it is simple. Is there a way to check for simplicity in infinite groups?

---

**UPDATE** (edit by YC)

The original question about the group $G$ has been answered below. Now I am up to the two groups $H := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{10}, ([a,b]^4b)^8 \rangle$ and
$I := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{10}, ([a,b]^4b)^9 \rangle$. I need to know if they are trivial, finite (the order would be good), or infinite.

Comment: Is the group infinite?

Comment: Yes, I have checked on the online magma calculator, and it is infinite. At least, it says 0, but I assume that means that it is infinite

Comment: I would not trust a calculator, especially if you do not really understand what it says.

Comment: It has been accurate so far. Also, just in case you wanted to know, the groups $G := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{10}, ([a,b]^4b)^n \rangle$, are the trivial group for n=1, 2, 3, 4, and 6, and it is PSL(2,41) for n=5.

Comment: Answer "0" may mean "infinite", or it may mean "stop asking these questions, go read a group theory book, and here is $\sin(\pi)$."

Comment: lol. Could you recommend a group theory book for me to read?

Comment: Finitely presented simple groups are very rare.  (The only examples that spring to mind are Thompson's groups V and T, and the square complexes constructed by Burger--Mozes.)  I don't know of any algorithm to certify that a group is simple.

Comment: You mean, infinite, finitely presented simple groups right?

Comment: @Thomas, yes, that's what I meant. Of course there are lots of finite examples.  Likewise, I was talking about algorithms that work with a presentation.

Comment: There is a way to tell if it is infinite though right? The presentation in the answer isn't quite the right one, it mixed up [a,b] with [a,b^-1], and thus gives a different group.

Comment: @Thomas, do you mean 'there are ways to tell if a group is infinite?' or 'there are ways to tell that a group is simple if it's infinite?'  The answer to the former is 'of course, lots', the answer to the second is 'only under very special circumstances'.

Comment: Okay then, I'll settle for testing if the group is infinite for now. Although, if there is there a way to find central elements, we might be able to prove that the group is not simple.

Comment: Actually, I found that the group has a quotient, so therefore it is not simple. I do still want to know whether it is infinite.

Comment: What was the quotient you found?

Comment: ([a,b][a,b^-1])^11 is the next relation to add, you can also add the relations (all at the same time): (ab[a,b]^2)^10, ((ab)^4(ab^-1)^2)^10, ([a,b][a,b^-1]^2)^8. Unfortunately, even after adding these relations, magma still can't determine the order of the group. Also, at each step I made sure the new relation wasn't already satisfied by the group

Comment: I went through the elements in lexicographical order (optimised quite a bit though), and for each one, I tried assigning an order to it, and then checked if the additional relation actually did anything to the group. It was actually quite surprising what relations emerged. For example, I never thought that an 11th power would be used.

Comment: Ok, I need results on this, I am not giving up my quest, so I'm placing a bounty on this question, which I will award to whomever can tell me whether H and I are trivial, finite (but not trivial, the order of the group would be nice too!), or infinite.

Comment: You should not have deleted the definition of the group $G$, because that has made the two answers to your original question incomprehensible.

Comment: @DerekHolt I just rolled back to the previous version and then added some clarification that the OP is now moving the goalposts.

Comment: Thomas, why exactly are you crunching through all these two-generator groups? As HJRW has pointed out here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139991/infinite-quotient-of-hurwitz-group#comment361227_139991 you seem to be on an open-ended mission and it is not clear what the goal is

Comment: Part of my goal is to find the "simplest" presentation of som of the 2-generator groups. For example, the janko group J1 has a presentation as a hurwitz group, but the order of the commutator is 19, whereas I found that there was a presentation (that I haven't nailed down yet) of the group where the order of the commutator is 10.

Comment: It's easy to compute presentations, but the problem is that they won't usually be nice. For example, $J_1$ has a presentation $\langle a,b \mid a^2,b^3,(ab)^7, [a,b]^{10}, uvuuvuuvvuvuuvvuvvuvuvuuvvuvvuvuv \rangle$, where $u=ab$ and $v=ab^{-1}$.

Comment: @Derek: you are making the last relation look extra-ugly :) (at least in the font I see on screen, $u$ and $v$ look almost the same) -- putting $r := uv$ and $s := u^2v^2r$ and using appropriate conjugation, you can turn this at least into $rs^2vr^2svr^3u$, if I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: Huh, that is interesting. I was hoping that it could be in terms of powers of an element. Is that the only relation that works?

Comment: I found that when you add the extra relation ([a,b]^4b)^11, it still contains the Janko group as a quotient. Maybe that would make the relations simpler.

Comment: Actually, I found a much better presentation for the Janko group. Just add the relation ([a,b]^2[a,b^2])^6.

Comment: So the presentation is ${J1} := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{10}, ([a,b]^2[a,b^2])^6 \rangle$

Comment: May I ask how you came up with your generator? The fact that it is shorter than mine (at least, when you expand mine out) suggests that you looked for the relations in terms of size. Did you use a program, or did you go through them by hand?

Answer (score 18):

In fact your group is trivial. Here are two different computations with Magma, the first using coset enumeration over the subgroup $\langle ab \rangle$, and the second using the Knuth-Bendix completion algorithm.

```
 > G<a,b>:=Group<a,b|a^2,b^3,(a*b)^7,(a,b)^10, ((a,b)^4*b)^7 >;
 > H:=sub<G|a*b>;
 > time Index(G,H:CosetLimit:=100000000,Hard:=true); 
 1
 Time: 27.730

 > time  R := RWSGroup(G:MaxRelations:=100000, TidyInt:=1000);
 Time: 90.350
 > Order(R);
 1
```

Comment: Being trivial is a good reason for not having many quotients.

Comment: Wait, so why did magma return 0 as the order when I asked for it?

Comment: Will this program work on the online calculator? Also, what about the other groups I mentioned?

Comment: The answer 0 just means that the program did not complete. That can cause some confusion, but no group can have order 0, so it cannot be interpreted as a valid answer. I think it needs too much memory for the Magma calculator. I've made no progress with your other two groups, so they could be trivial too or they could be infinite. They don't appear to have any reasonably sized finite simple quotients, so I have no ideas about how they might be proved infinite.

Comment: Is there another (free) group theory program than the magma online calculator that can compute these things?

Comment: Is there a name for the groups: $G := \langle a, b \ | \ a^m, b^n, (ab)^p, [a,b]^q \rangle$? This is so that I can google the name and perhaps find some interesting papers on the subject. I know the groups have been referred to as (m,n,p;q) groups, but googling that doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: The paper: G. Havas and D.F. Holt.
On Coxeter's families of group presentations.
Journal of Algebra 324 (2010), 1076--1082, which you can find at
http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~mareg/download/papers/coxpres/coxpres.pdf might be useful as a starting point, and for further references.

Comment: Wait a minute, are you the Derek F Holt in the paper?

Comment: I didn't get another answer to my question, so I am awarding it to you, since you were the most helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I think Mark Sapir's cautionary joke that magma is just returning a value of $sin(\pi)$ is actually surprisingly accurate. The "Order" function on a finitely presented group, denoted by magma as GrpFP, Magma returns positive integer if the group is computed to be finite, "Infinity" if the group is known to be infinite (e.g. a map to $\mathbb{Z}$ exists), and "0" when its certificates of infinite order cannot be established, coset enumeration exhausts memory, and magma can't determine the order of the group.

http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/773#8529

EDIT: The OP uses $[a,b]=a\cdot b^{-1} \cdot a^{-1} \cdot b$, my explanation below is $[a,b]=a\cdot b \cdot a^{-1} \cdot b^{-1}$. The computation of Order with the OP's definition returns a 0, as noted in the comments below.

Having said all that, the magma computation I ran gave a different answer for $G$. Magma is saying $G$ is trivial. I used a machine at the University of Texas, which might have more available memory for coset enumeration than the online magma calculator.

$
> G<a,b>:=Group<a,b|a^\wedge 2,b^\wedge 3,(a*b)^\wedge 7,(a*b*a^\wedge -1*b^\wedge -1)^\wedge 10,((a*b*a^\wedge -1*b^\wedge -1)^\wedge 4*b)^\wedge 7\
>;\\
> Order(G);\\                                                                    
1\\
$

However, the orders of $H$ and $I$ don't seem to be computable with the available memory, so they might be infinite and they might not be.

Comment: [a,b]=ab^-1ab, not abab^-1, I'm not sure, but it may make a difference.

Comment: I checked on magma, and the presentation you used does result in the trivial group, so they are different.

Comment: I also checked what you said earlier, and you're right, magma should show infinity, but it shows zero because it couldn't figure it out. Is there a way to check whether it is infinite? Also, are there any other groups theory calculators that you recommend?

Comment: I think you may be able to check that the group normally generated by $[a,b]^{10}, ([a,b]^4 b)^n$ for $n\geq 7$ is infinite index in $\langle a, b| a^2,b^3,c^7\rangle$, which is an index 2 subgroup of a hyperbolic triangle group.

Comment: That it is what? Infinite? Simple? Also, how will I be able to check? Some group theory program? By hand?

Comment: Woops, didn't see the last part. Sorry. Still, how do I check?

Comment: Actually, I use a^-1b^-1ab, but a^-1=a anyway in this group, so it is ab^-1ab